# Is the complement of the language generated by $S \to aSbS|\epsilon$ context-free?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, formal-grammars

How is it possible to prove whether the language $\{a, b\}^{∗} \setminus \{S → ε, S → aSbS\}$ is context free?

Answer (score 1):

The first step is finding a simpler description of the language generated by the grammar $S \to aSbS \mid \epsilon$.

The second step is deducing a description of the complement, which is the language you're actually interested in.

Finally, in order to show that the language is context-free, you can consult our [reference question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/18524/how-to-prove-that-a-language-is-context-free) on this topic.